# Синонимизировать метки [рисование], [draw]

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Я считаю что нужно синонимизировать метки:

- [рисование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) - 63 вопроса
- [draw](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/draw) - 34 вопроса

Основная метка - [рисование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)

Comment: Графика - это шире, чем рисование, там еще есть вот такие вопросы: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/236813/240512 Если синонимизировать, то только [рисование] и [draw]

Comment: @MSDN.WhiteKnight если честно, я не вижу смысла в отдельной метке для рисования (для графики тоже, но там хоть описание оформлено и вопросов довольно много). Я бы со спокойной душой метки слил. По поводу вопроса по ссылке - у меня есть большие сомнения, что метка "графика" там необходима. Там больше про разбор графического формата, а не про графику, там бы имел смысл в более конкретной метки. Хотя она уже есть - это метка png.

Comment: Ок, удалил "графику", скопипастил с небольшими поправками краткое описание в "рисование"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Готово!

```
updating post history, 38 rows affected (pipe delimited)
updating posts, 34 rows affected  (pipe delimited)
updating PostTags associations, 34 rows affected
updating ForYou nudges, 0 rows affected
destroying 'draw': [draw] removed from (0 post, 0 history, 1 tag)
total: 1 tags deleted, 0 posts modified, 0 post histories modified
0 history records for type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
0 post records of type Question had empty tags; retagged to [untagged]
updating count for target tag, new count: 97
tag remapping of [рисование] and [draw] complete!
remapping 0 synonyms
1 favorite and ignored tags remapped!
0 tracked tag badges were remapped!
Tag Synonym draw -> рисование was approved!
```